# How to select new opened window in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, popup

I'm trying to solve a little problem.

There is a web page - there is a button on this web page. When I click on this button, a new window is opened.

I'm curious, how to tell the `Selenium` that I want to see a page source of this new window?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to the other window. Since the webdriver can only deal with your existing windows , you need to look into the window handling. You can find an example regarding switching windows below:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://hdfcbank.com");
        Thread.sleep(6000L);

        Actions mouse = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement address = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[7]/div[1]/span"));
        mouse.moveToElement(address).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
        String parenthandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); // current window handle
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='goldloan']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000L);
        for (String windowhandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {

            driver.switchTo().window(windowhandle); // switches to next window
        }
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtFName']")).sendKeys("testing");
        driver.close();
        driver.switchTo().window(parenthandle);
```